# R testthat results differ from running test file with Rscript

Tags: r, testing, testthat

I am new to programming in R and have come across a baffling issue with testthat and Rscript.

I have a test file, call it `test.R`, that contains a bunch of `testthat::test_that("test_name", {testthat::expect ...})` statements.  If I run `Rscript test.R`, or if I just paste the statements from the test into the R console and manually check that the `expect` would pass, everything works as expected and my tests seem to succeed.

However, if I use `library(devtools); devtools::test()`, there is a failing test with a subscript out of bounds error.

I haven't included any specific code because I'm not looking to try to debug the particular error, but rather hope to understand how this is possible.  Would `testthat` be running a different version?  Is there differing behaviour between `Rscript` and the R console compared to what `testthat` would run under?

Comment: Is your package source code available publicly, e.g. in a GitHub repo?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Can you post the complete error message/output from `devtools::test()`? I know I'm asking questions about specifics when you're looking for a broader answer, but finding the specific problem may help an answerer find the particular broader topic that needs to be addressed.

Comment: It just says it has encountered an error "subscript out of bounds", and then points to the line causing the error.

There is a seemingly similar error here: https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/700, but adding calls to context() did not help my issue.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I experienced the same problem.

In my case, the objects created in the script *were not **exactly** the same* as those created in a test `helper` file, so the tests were receiving *slightly* different information to the script, and hence were returning different results.